# How to expect program exit in gtest?

Tags: c++, exit, googletest, glog

I'm testing some code that uses `CHECK` from [glog](https://google-glog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/glog.html) and I'd like to test that this check fails in certain scenarios. My code looks like:

```
void MyClass::foo() {
  // stuff...
  // It's actually important that the binary gets aborted if this flag is false
  CHECK(some_flag) << "flag must be true";

  // more stuff...
}
```

I've done some research into `gtest` and how I might be able to test for this. I found `EXPECT_FATAL_FALIURE`, `EXPECT_NONFATAL_FAILURE`, and `HAS_FATAL_FAILURE` but I haven't managed to figure out how to use them. I'm fairly confident that if I change `CHECK(some_flag)` to `EXPECT_TRUE(some_flag)` then `EXPECT_FATAL_FAILURE` will work correctly but then I'm introducing test dependencies in non-test files which is...icky.

Is there a way for `gtest` to catch the abort signal (or whatever `CHECK` raises) and expect it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

aaaand I found an answer 5 minutes after posting this question. Typical.

This can be done using [Death tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#death-tests) from gtest. Here's how my test looks:

```
TEST(MyClassTest, foo_death_test) {
  MyClass clazz(false); // make some_flag false so the CHECK fails
  ASSERT_DEATH( { clazz.foo(); }, "must be true");
}
```

This passes. Woohoo!